# Why keeps returning me the ORA-01403 error?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11gr2

Hello guys when I'm running my code in a query everything seems to walk fine, but when I put it within a stored procedure it returns me the 'No data found error'.

I used an exception handling error but it returns me the same error.

```
create or replace procedure test(i_d number)
as
  l_text VARCHAR(900);
begin
  select 'TEST, '||to_char(D3,'yy.mm.dd')|| CHR(10)||'STRINGTEXT'||D2
    into l_text
  from table
  where id = i_d;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
  -- do something
  dbms_output.put_line('No records found for employee no ');

end;
```

what can I do?

Comment: Are you sure the i_d you are passing is present in table?

Comment: The error indicates that the SELECT statement did not return a row, so the condition `where id = i_d` apparently evaluates to false

Comment: can you please help me a little more? i_d is a parameter...

Comment: I specify the id as a number which is in the table (eg id=5) but it keeps returning me the error..

Comment: I also tried to erase the where clause and it also returns me an error..

Comment: Try to edit your query to get `count(*)` instead of `'TEST, '||to_varchar(D3,'yy.mm.dd')|| CHR(10)||'STRINGTEXT'||D2` and then print the result.

Comment: TO_VARCHAR isn't a valid command, try TO_CHAR... Is the code you are showing us the  code you are running?

Comment: @HereGoes I changed this but with no success... the error appears in lines 5 and 6..
when I run the procedure as execute test(5) it returns me only 'commands completed successfully' and not the select

Comment: @Aleksej the same error when i select count(*)

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yes absolutely sure...

Comment: @helloandroiddevelopers your procedure is not written to return anything. Why do you expect it to?

Comment: @Boneist hello, when I run the stored procedure(as a store procedure and not as execute test(5);) returns me errors... and not 'Process exited'

Comment: I see too many strange things here; `to_varchar` is not an Oracle function; you could even have a user-defined function with that name, but this sounds strange. Even if you had this function, your procedure would not compile anyway, because you use `i_empno`, which is never declared. Also the fact that your procedure raises a `no_data_found` even if you do `select count` sounds strange. Are your sure this procedure is compiled? Can you please post the code you use to call the procedure?

Comment: @helloandroiddevelopers what do you mean when say `when I run the stored procedure (as a stored procedure and not as execute test(5);)`? `execute test(5)` **is** running the code as a stored procedure! What is the other way you have been running the code? (Please edit your question to add that information in)

Comment: @Boneist i open the procedure from the left side and then I click run

Comment: @Aleksej i deleted already your notices so i will edit my code and here! Yes, the procedure was full compiled but when i re-open it as i wrote above, it returns me this erros

Comment: Where are you running this procedure? In PL/SQL Developer? Toad? SQL Developer? Something else?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a column `i_d`, other than `id` in your table?

Comment: @Boneist in PL/SQL Developer

Comment: @Aleksej the i_d column is not a table column.. it is a parameter :) which matches and returns us the id from table

Comment: I see that it's a parameter, but if you even had a column with that name in your table, this could lead Oracle to ignore the parameter value, checking the equality between the two table columns,

Comment: @Aleksej i don't have a column with this name in any table

Comment: @helloandroiddevelopers then don't run it from the left. Where do you see "Run" when you click on the procedure name on the left hand side anyway? Which tab are you in - the Objects tab?

Comment: @Boneist i open the code of the procedure and then press 'Run'

Comment: @helloandroiddevelopers you mean you press the green play button? If so, all you're doing there is compiling the procedure, you're not running it.

Comment: @Boneist exactly.... so what can I do now? :/

Comment: You run it in the SQL (or command) window, passing the relevant parameters. E.g. `begin your_procedure(your_parameter(s)); end;`

Comment: @Boneist and it's says only PL/SQL procedure successfully completed..

it isn't supposed to return me  value or a table?

Comment: No, not unless you tell it to. You have no out parameters to return any values, so you shouldn't expect to see anything being returned. Maybe (if this is for testing purposes only), you could add a `dbms_output.put_line` line in your code to output something to the Output tab. This is **NOT** recommended for production code, however.

Comment: @Boneist I'm so very confused.. how can i see the change of the parameter that I executed? The difference between the test(2) and the test(3)?
And is it right that when i recompile the procedure, it returns me the errors and then the 'process excited'?

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this procedure? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Here's a couple of ways you could do what I think you're trying to do: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a3ec4e565b6ca074a8ad024ac92b4b02 The function way is, IMO, better for this particular query.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain the whole part of what you are doing **"--do something"** inside your **exception part** ? the only way I see is an error could be raised inside the Exception part which would ideally through the error.

Can you provide the sample table structure and data set to test this scenario. It would be great if you could share a livesql link so that we could help you out.

You can use LiveSQL - https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000

Also can you try to change the select statement as below, and try to run the proc to make sure its not due to the to_char function.

select 'TEST, '|| D3 || CHR(10)||'STRINGTEXT'||D2 into l_text

Comment: It's not due to the char function, I checked that... How can I use LiveSql to provide you my query?

Comment: is it possible for you to share the exception code part ?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing to_varchar(D3,'yy.mm.dd') with to_char(D3,'yy.mm.dd')

Comment: thank you, I tried this but this wasn't the error :/

Comment: run select * from table, (table being the name of your table), then take an id from the data returned and try runnging: select 'TEST, '||to_char(D3,'yy.mm.dd')|| CHR(10)||'STRINGTEXT'||D2
  from table
  where id = (here put the id)

Comment: yes,and  i clear it everytime I execute the changed code

Comment: what dbms are you running this on?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Please review the help section [ask]. Using that as a guild is much more likely to get a satisfactory answer. In this particular case include the table DDL, sample data (as text not an image) and the expected output of that data.  At one point you indicated that if you don't get ORA-01403 then all you get is "procedure successfully completed", This is because the data was read into your variable but then didn't do anything with it.  Sort of like shell script  "#!/bin/bash

read varname"

Comment: @Belayer i wrote that when I execute the query such as (exec test(5) ) it returns me the 'commands completed successfully"..
but when i try to rerun the stored procedure it returns me the ora error..